# Validación del nombre de los headers al importar excel

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy utilizando laravel excel para importar un excel a mi app. Pero me encuentro con un problema y es que necesito validar el nombre de las cabeceras de las filas y validar que se importe el archivo con el formato correcto.

Intente hacer la validación, pero no esta funcionando. Es como si no se estuviera ejecutando la validación.

Así lo tengo en mi import.

```
public function model(array $row)
{

    return new Factura([
        'documento'         => $row['rnc_cedula'],
        'tipo_documento'    => $row['tipo_de_identificacion'],
        'ncf'               => $row['ncf'],
    )]
}
```

Esta es la validacion de las cabeceras:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        // Fila.columna
        '0.0'   => 'in:rnc_cedula',
        '0.1'   => 'in:tipo_de_identificacion',
        '0.2'   => 'in:ncf',
    ];
}
```

En el controlador estoy intentando atrapar el error:

```
try{
            Excel::import($import, $request->archivo );
        } 
        catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
            $failures = $e->failures();
            
            foreach ($failures as $failure) {
                $failure->row(); // row that went wrong
                $failure->attribute(); // either heading key (if using heading row concern) or column index
                $failure->errors(); // Actual error messages from Laravel validator
                $failure->values(); // The values of the row that has failed.
            }
        }
```

Y si trato de importar un archivo que no tiene este formato me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuidado con los nombres de las cabeceras, rnc_cedula debe ser rnc cedula en excel, debido a que las cabeceras se traducen con el helper slug() de laravel. También debido a que entiendo que estás utilizando HeadingRow, la validación se debe hacer con el nombre de la cabecera, como indican en la documentación: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#validating-with-a-heading-row De todos modos, trata de publicar todo el codigo de tu import

Comment: @ItsEdgar94 Gracias por responder. He cambiado el nombre de varias formas y aun así no funciona. He revisado la documentación pero los ejemplos que veo solo es para validar los datos, no el nombre de la cabecera en si.